# How to add two different paths to the same endpoint in swagger?

Tags: java, documentation, swagger, java-ws

Using javaws we can have multiple endpoints leading to the same method. Example:

```java
@Path("/menus")
public class MenuResource {
    @Path("/{menuId}/sections")
    @Timed @ExceptionMetered
    public MenuSectionResource getSections(@InjectParam MenuSectionResource resource) {
        return resource;
    }
}

@Path("/sections")
public class MenuSectionResource {
    @GET
    public Section get(@PathParam("menuId") String menuId, @QueryParam("id") String id) {
        /// method accessed by GET in /sections or GET in /menus/{menuid}/sections
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use swagger to document both endpoints, but i can only use one
`@Api` annotation in each class, so i can generate either `/sections` or `/menus/{menuid}/sections`. Is it possible to automatically generate both entries in the swagger.json output?

Comment: Is your code valid? Shouldn't this `@Path("/{menuId}/sections")`  be on method in `MenuSectionResource` class? Where is a real problem? Can you clarify your problem?

Comment: Yeah the code is valid. That method is an entry point to another resource. Problem is using swagger annotations i can't document menus/ID/sections i can only document /sections, as it's only one method.

Comment: Hey can you clarify about how are you trying to add swagger annotations?

Comment: @Samarth well that's the problem. Following the docs i can add annotations that ties a method to an endpoint but i don't even know where to start to document both endpoints.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: @Simon nope. I gave up and built this manually.